# Why isn't this property merging in Object.assign?

Tags: javascript

So I have a function like this:

```
    const photosWithTempId = files.map(file => {
      const tempId = generateTempId(file);
      console.log("tempId: ", tempId);
      return Object.assign(file, {
        ["id"]: tempId,
        ["filename"]: file.name,
        ["downloadUrl"]: file.preview,
      });
    });
```

It's supposed to add a temporal id alongside with two additional fields `filename` and `downloadUrl`

Problem is that the returned `File object` does not have the `id` property, but it does have the new `filename` and `downloadUrl` properties:

```
File {
  name: "pipboy.gif"
  lastModified: 1588020743900
  lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 27 2020 23:52:23 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) {}
  webkitRelativePath: ""
  size: 30265
  type: "image/gif"
  preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/f0cafa2b-82a1-4652-bbaa-234c4fc1b8b6"
  index: 0
  progress: 0
  uploadState: "NOT_STARTED"
  fieldsToPost: {filename: "pipboy.gif", originalFilename: "pipboy.gif"}
  filename: "pipboy.gif"
  downloadUrl: "blob:http://localhost:3000/f0cafa2b-82a1-4652-bbaa-234c4fc1b8b6"
}
```

`generateTempId(file)` is a function that returns a randomly generated string id like `tempId_50481707`

```
export const generateTempId = file =>
  !file["id"]
    ? TEMP_ID + Math.floor(Math.random() * RANDOM_TEMP_NUMBER)
    : file["id"];
```

The final object should have the property `id: tempId_50481707` but it does not.

Comment: Realize that you can use `{ id: tempId, filename: file.name, downloadUrl: file.preview }` instead of all of those brackets, unless you're trying to do something else with that construct...

Comment: For inconveniences I changed the fields for this stack overflow post only, the fields look like this in the real code:
        [PHOTO.API_FIELD_ID]: tempId,
        [PHOTO.API_FIELD_FILENAME]: file.name,
        [PHOTO.API_FIELD_DOWNLOAD_URL]: file.preview,

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at you object after looping through the map, 
Is `PHOTO.API_FIELD_ID` not `index` ? Try to add an another field to see if it's added

Comment: Ah, okay, well bravo for simplifying! We like that. You can go even farther though :). It would be great if you could create a [mre] that reproduces the problem. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create one here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/6emabrz7/1/

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but if that's [a built-in `File` object from the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) that you're extending, you might be running into conflicts with a hidden property the browser is using (and why it's not encouraged to extend built-in objects).

Comment: "running into conflicts with a hidden property the browser is using"
...This must be it. The `id` field of a `File` object cannot be modified or added. I set the `tempId` value to `filename` and it did show up on the returned `File` object.